# Control Key for Home & End on Command-line in Terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: command-line-interface, shell

What are the control keys to move the cursor to the beginning and end of the command-line? The Home and End keys don't work in Terminal on Mac OS X.

Comment: http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ctrl-A and ctrl-E

Answer (score 0):

`shift-Home` and `Shift-End` will work.
So will disabling the brain-damaged default Home & End behavior:

1. Open Terminal Preferences->Settings
2. Select your profile
3. On the Keyboard tab find & remove the bindings for Home (scroll to start of buffer) & End (scroll to end of buffer)

Comment: (Note that if your console app treats the `shift-home`/`shift-end` combo specially the above won't work, so I recommend disabling the brain-damaged default behavior :-)

Comment: I like this answer, too, but I can't mark both.